# Time String from Webpage

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

Here is the Html

```
<li class="right-boarder"><a style="cursor: auto">09-Nov-2014 [17:39:07 IST]</a></li>
```

string x

Now I am trying to set x = to the time string from above Html (17:39:07)

and Then I will reset my clock with this x value.

How I extract time string from above Html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using C# Regex

```
string input = @"<li class=""right-boarder""><a style=""cursor: auto"">09-Nov-2014 [17:39:07 IST]</a></li>";

//find "[dd:dd:dd ABC]" - 2 digits separated by colon, and space and 3 alphabets
string pattern = @"\[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s[A-Z]{3}\]";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    x = matches[0].Value.Split(' ')[0].Replace("[", "");
}
```

### Output

```
"17:39:07"
```

Comment: Great Sir, Successfully implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery you can do something like this

```
var x = $(".right-boarder").text()
```

Or using Javascript you can do something like this

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('right-boarder').innerHTML;
```

Also if you want to extract the time only and not the date you can do something like

```
var y = x.substr(x.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```

- 1 to remove the first space

Comment: Just give this element a unique id and get it using the Id by document.getElementById("SomeId").innerHTML;

Comment: Not my own website. Developing automate functionality. Can I take advantage of [].